# GridStack how to disable moving or dragging grid widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridstack

As the title suggests, I have issues disabling moving or dragging grid widgets. I have tried using `data-gs-no-move`, `data-gs-locked`and `data-gs-no-resize` as listed in GridStack documents, but it still draggable and moveable in my browser. Is there any workarounds to it?

Currently using `GridStack 0.2.6`.

Comment: Could you post parts of your code? Otherwise it'll be hard to find the actual problem.

Comment: I've been following the docs too and am totally baffled how to toggle the grid. Did you figure anything out?

Answer (score 3):

Add the data attribute `data-gs-no-move="yes"` to the grid-stack-item, as demonstrated below.

```
<div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-no-move="yes">
   <div class="grid-stack-item-content">
       <!-- content goes here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

If you need to prevent it from being moved when another item is dragged, then you will also need to the `data-gs-locked="yes"` attribute.

If you want to stop it being resized, then add the `data-gs-no-resize="yes"` attribute.

You can mix and match as you require.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-gs-no-move="yes"` and `data-gs-no-resize="yes"`. `locked` refers only to other widgets affecting the widget in question.

PS - The docs are h*ckin old. I'll update them soon and hopefully they won't leave anyone baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get this to work using the previous answers, but this did using the latest version of GridStack (v7.2.3):

```
grid.update($gridItem, {
  locked: true,
  noResize: true,
  noMove: true
});
```

Where `$gridItem` is the HTML element of the grid item you want to update, or you can use a class string.